# Subscribing to HttpInterceptor errors, angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The application I am working on previously had a HTTP interceptor which had been manually written - it looked a bit like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService extends Http {

  onError: EventEmitter<Response> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options).catch((error: Response) => {
      this.onError.emit(error);
      // other stuff
      return Observable.throw(error);
    });
  }
}
```

The `onError` EventEmitter is important, as a service called `notifications.service.ts` used that to subscribe to it and update the UI if an error occurred.

I have been working on upgrading this application to Angular 5, which has involved removing all the `HttpModule` code and replacing it with `HttpClient`. I also had to update the `HttpInterceptorService`, so it now looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  onError: EventEmitter<HttpErrorResponse> = new EventEmitter();

  public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.onError.emit(error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }
}
```

The Interceptor and `HttpClientModule` are implemented in the app.module.ts in the standard way (according to the docs). This works well, and the interceptor is used when the application runs and HTTP requests are made. However, to make it work, I had to remove the notification service, as when I try to run it with that service injected into a few components, a console error simply says: `No provider for HttpInterceptorService!`. I have tried adding a provider for the HttpInterceptorService to the relevant module files, but it hasn't worked.

So my question is, what is the standard way of subscribing to the errors caught in the HttpInterceptor and consuming them in another service?

Comment: Each call to `HttpClient` request method returns an observable, you listen for errors on that observable. If any of the interceptors throw an error, it will be delivered through the observable

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com thanks. I have used the HttpClient observable to subscribe to some errors, but this is more for a global system across the entire application. If any HttpRequest fails, for whatever reason, I want it to immediately emit an error using the EventEmitter, which any other service or component can subscribe to. Is this still possible? I think I could create an additional service which would do this (`HttpInterceptorError`) or something - just wondering if there's a way to keep it inside this main interceptor service?

Comment: and how do you want to proceed with the error delivered by interceptor?